# Illegal Offset type where key is a string

Tags: php

```
function Normalise($holder) {
    $holder = explode(" ",$holder);
    $norm = "";
    foreach($holder as $Word) {
        $Letter1 = substr($Word,0,1);
        $Letter1 = strtoupper($Letter1);
        $body = substr($Word,1);
        $body = strtolower($body);
        $norm = $norm.$Letter1.$body." "; 
    }
    $norm = substr($norm,0,-1);
    return $norm;
}


$m = "Reason:@:0";
$c = explode(":@:",$m);
$Garrr = (string)Normalise($c[0]);
$Huff = array([$Garrr] => $c[1]);
echo gettype($Garrr);
array_merge($ReasonNumbers,$Huff);
```

This is the section of code I'm debugging. gettype confirms that $Garrr is a string. Yet I'm still getting a Illegal Offset Type error. I can't find out for the life of me why this is and while I am loathe to put it online, I really have been at it for too long. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you? Can you at least give us what $m is?

Comment: Sorry, it's up there. If you need any more information I'll gladly put it up, I just wanted to make the question as succinct as possible.

Comment: Ok then let's keep going. What is `Normalise`?

Comment: Is this something like you are expecting? https://3v4l.org/iQ5dN

Comment: Is what something I was expecting? The idea is to create an array where the thing on the left of the :@: is the key and the thing on the right is the value.

Comment: Well gosh could I mean the link in the comment? Jisses! Anyways, your "Normalise" is probably the same as http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php

Comment: Apologies if my comment seemed overly aggressive, that was not the tone I had intended to convey. Normalise seems to do the same thing as ucwords, and i'll probably implement that as soon as I iron out this bug, thank you for pointing it out. The link is what I was expecting, thank you for doing that, didn't see it when I wrote the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to build your own ucwords.
Ucwords creates what is known as camel case, capitalizing each word in a sentence.

Not sure if the $ReasonNumbers is created elsewhere but it needs to exist if you want to use array_merge.
And array_merge returns the array so a `=` is needed.

And [$Garr] should be $Garr.

```
$ReasonNumbers = [];

$m = "reason here:@:0";
$c = explode(":@:",$m);
$Garrr = ucwords($c[0]);
$Huff = array($Garrr => $c[1]);
//echo gettype($Garrr);
$ReasonNumbers = array_merge($ReasonNumbers,$Huff);
Var_dump($ReasonNumbers);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["Reason Here"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

https://3v4l.org/pDf7Z

Answer (score 0):

The "Illegal Offset type" error is related to incorrect use of array indexes, for example, using an *Object* type instead of number or plain string.

```
$array = array("a", "b", "c");
$obj = new stdClass();
$value = $array[$obj]; // this doesn't work
```

So, you need to check the lines using an Object as index.
Using `gettype`($var) you can check if the returned value is object [http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php]

if `$Garr` is an Object, you need to use another type of index, for example getting a hash from the object with `spl_object_hash` [http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php]

Comment: I am getting the "Illegal offset type" error even when the variable is a string, and I've checked that using gettype.

Comment: You can check if the error message is related to that line or maybe another one. If not, please post a question with your current code